# Managed mobile application monitoring performance

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, monitoring, metrics

What is the best mobile application monitoring solution you know?

**With the following requirements:**

> - Managed solution
> - Support for **Unity3d** client
> - Monitor CPU, memory
> - Ability to send custom events
> - Ability to send events for specific device (Ability to drill down later for this specific device)

I found [new relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-unity) solution for example, but it is a bit expensive, also I'm not sure about the device drill down abilities.